# The provided key does not have access to account in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

This is my stripe code in which I receive the error

> The provided key does not have access to account in stripe

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_...');
$fees=($request->amount*10)/100;
$fees=$fees*100;
$withfee = \Stripe\Charge::create(
  array(
    "amount" => 10000,//1000, //$amount amount in cents
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => "tok_1BGovzDnnXvdHsSaayDkULRU",//'tok_18L6hjL6useUrEYbtObKz15s', 
//$token
    "description" => "Example charge",//"Example charge", //$title
    "application_fee" => 1000 // amount in cents //$fees
  ),
  array("stripe_account" => "cus_Be21HSwLO1XMhF" ) // $acc_token 
);
```

Comment: I don't know the API but I'd guess you either don't have permission or supplied the wrong credentials.

Answer (score 13):

You are passing a customer ID (`"cus_..."`) in the [`stripe_account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) field.

When [processing a charge with Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges), you need to provide the ID of the account (`"acct_..."`) on behalf of which you are processing the charge. [Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) are payment sources (i.e. they provide funds) while [accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object) are payment destinations (i.e. they receive funds).